# Zoom in and out changes the original shape of Charts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, nivo-slider

[image]

Using the React-nivo library to developing charts, and I have this issue with almost all charts. Once we zoom out and zoom in, and reset your browser to default 100%, the charts don't retain their original shape.

[Refer here for images](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp16vvz6n7?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: in the css, try changing the `flex-direction` to `column`...

Comment: I actually have two charts aligned next to eachother

Comment: The [answer](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/LYGvdMg?editors=0012) to your latest question (deleted one)

Comment: Yevgen, thank you so much! :)